# Tool to record WATIR scripts?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, web-testing, test-tools

I need a tool to record browser action and generate WATIR scripts. Is there any tool available for this?

Comment: [This?](http://3qilabs.com/news/awetest-recorder-record-cucumber-watir-webdriver-tests/).

Comment: record browser action and generate WATIR scripts